# How to create new columns in pandas based on database in code memory?

Tags: python, pandas

I have csv files that contain just 1 column with 10 digit numbers (product codes). I need to create a second column that cuts the products codes to 5 digits (beginning only, which is a category of the product). But I also need to create a third and fourth column based on some info that I have stored in python code. So depending on the first 5 digits (category of the product)it could be fishing supplies, camping supplies and ex. Also depending on those 5 digit it could be warehouse 1,2,3 ex. This is what I need to see in those additional columns after comparing to the saved database, which has all that info.

Reading my file (only 1 column name `numbers` and 10 digit numbers in this column) The file looks like this:

```
numbers  
2324564567  
2324564231  
6343323124  
2425423235  
2322112532
```

By the way, the file in the csv text format
I was able to create the second column `categories`.

so I get:

```
numbers          categories  
2324564567       23245  
2324564231       23245  
6343323124       63433  
2425423235       24254  
2322112532       23221
```

Now I am stuck with the 3rd and 4th columns. Based on categories I need to create 2 more columns to identify what category and what warehouse the product located at. I have lists that have the name of the categoies, the ware house number and all 5 digit numbers of the category. Then I make the main list of the lists.

Please see the example of my lists:

```
fishing = ["Fishing supplies", "Warehouse3", "23245", "25122", "24254", "23221"]  
camping = ["Camping supplies", "Warehouse1", "63433", "53466", "63335"]  
lightning = ["Lightning supplies", "Warehouse2", "35223", "24222", 21232"]
```

the last objects in lists above are categories which I based everything on]
Also I have the lists of the lists:

```
all_products = [Fishing, Camping, Lightning]
```

So the idea is to create iteration (its needed right?) where the code is going to take every row of my second column (5 digit) and compare it to All_products lists. Find the list that includes these 5 digit, and take the [0] from there, which is the name of category and put it in the 3rd column. Then take the [1] object, which is the Warehouse name and put in in the 4th column. So the results should look like this:

```
numbers          categories      name                     location  
2324564567       23245           Fishing supplies         Warehouse3  
2324564231       23245           Fishing supplies         Warehouse3  
6343323124       63433           Camping supplies         Warehouse1  
2425423235       24254           Fishing supplies         Warehouse3  
2322112532       23221           Fishing supplies         Warehouse3
```

I tried things like `.loc`, `.iloc`, `isin()`, indexing and `vlookup`.

```
#reading my input file
data = pd.read_csv("Book1.csv")  
#loading my lists in memory
```

creating second column

```
for index, row in data.iterrows()
    data[‘categories’] = data[numbers].astype.str.slice(:6)
```

Don't have any working code for 3rd and 4th column, which is what I need help with.

Comment: do you know how to merge? you can merge your first csv from the `category` column onto the lists (a more flexible vlookup if you will)

Comment: Hi ! I tried, but it is hard to merge df with lists, I had to transform my lists into df first, as the solution below

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, best approach would be to restructure data in your lists. There is too much varied information in one single list.

You can achieve your result by doing following steps:

```
# to get categories you can just do
df["categories"] = df["Numbers"].astype(str).str.slice(6)
df.head()

#      Numbers categories
#0  2324564567      23245
#1  2324564231      23245
#2  6343323124      63433
#3  2425423232      24254
#4  2322112532      23221


# restructure the data in lists to dictionary
product_ids = {}
for prod_list in all_products: 
    prod_name = prod_list[0] 
    warehouse = prod_list[1] 
    for prod_id in prod_list[2:]: 
        product_ids[prod_id] = {"name": prod_name, "warehouse": warehouse}

# Now we can convert this to a dataframe which can be joined with our original dataframe
product_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(product_ids, orient='index')

df = df.join(product_df, on='categories')
df.head()

#      Numbers categories              name   warehouse
#0  2324564567      23245  Fishing supplies  Warehouse3
#1  2324564231      23245  Fishing supplies  Warehouse3
#2  6343323124      63433  Camping supplies  Warehouse1
#3  2425423232      24254  Fishing supplies  Warehouse3
#4  2322112532      23221  Fishing supplies  Warehouse3
```

Comment: Wow! This is great! The solution of transferring my lists into the df is just perfect! I will try use this logic in the future as well. Thank you so much for such a great advice! Good luck with everything!